# This should be so simple, but I can't get it to work

Tags: c#

I wrote a simple c# program to automate the process of signing files and I just can't get it to work. Sorry, but I'm no expert in C# (obviously)! Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] 
        // This progam makes it easy to remember the parameters that need to be passed to signtool and automates the process

        if (args.Length < 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: SignFile FileToSign .pfxfile Password");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string signTool = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Bin\\signtool.exe\"";
                string fileToSign = args[0];
                string pfxFile = args[1];
                string password = args[2];
                string commandLine = "/C " + signTool + " sign /f \"" + pfxFile + "\" /fd SHA256 /p "
                    + password + @" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll " + fileToSign;
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(".");
                startInfo.Arguments = commandLine;
                Process process = new Process();
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run it I get 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I also tried using the short version of the directory name:

```
string signTool = "\"c:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~2\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Bin\\signtool.exe\"";
```

But this I get:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I could say more, but I think I'll leave this as simple as it is...

Comment: try using string signTool ="c:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~2\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Bin\\signtool.exe\"; refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe

Comment: Is there a reason you are using cmd.exe rather than invoking the tool directly?

Comment: Regarding comment 1 I get: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with @ in front, like this:

```
string signTool = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\signtool.exe""";
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was fixed by comment 2 on my original question:

[image]